# Flexbox media query issue

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design

I have a very simple two col layout and I am trying to make it responsive, but the media query keeps getting trumped.

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item-left is-mobile">1</div>
  <div class="flex-item-right is-mobile">2</div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex-item-left {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 50%;
}

.flex-item-right {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 50%;
}

/* Responsive layout - makes a one column-layout instead of a two-column layout */
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .flex-item-right.is-mobile, .flex-item-left.is-mobile {
    flex: 100% !important;
  }
}
```

Is CSS specificity at play here? Weird thing is it works on screen resizes but not on an actual mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

So I have to answer my own question so it will help someone else. The issue was I was not setting the `viewport` for the mobile devices, and the page was rendering in non-mobile viewport mode.  From a different post:

> You need to set your viewport meta tag to content="width=device-width,
> initial-scale=1". This tells the browser to render the width of the
> page at the width of the device's screen. So if that screen is 320px
> wide, the browser window will be 320px wide, rather than way zoomed
> out and showing 960px (or whatever that device does by default).

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Looks like if you don't add a viewport setting of `width=device-width` it will default to `980px` which is certainly higher for my above media query to not apply!

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-12 bg-danger">
      1 of 2
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-12 bg-primary">
      2 of 2
    </div>
  </div>
```

I suggest you use a bootstrap. There are different modes for responsiveness

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Answer (score 0):

```
width: 100%
```

for flex-item-left and flex-item-right

or this:

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
    .flex-container {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}
```